# paginate a subquery in flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pagination

This is an abbreviated version of the problem posted in [Strange paginate behaviour when paginating a subquery in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282132/strange-paginate-behaviour-when-paginating-a-subquery-in-flask).

I need to paginate the result of the following query and display the results:

```py
sub = db.session.query(Magazine).join(Magazine.subscribers).filter(User.id == 2).subquery()
subscribers = db.session.query(User).select_from(sub).join(Magazine.subscribers)
```

and I try to do it with the following code:

```py
page=request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
friends=subscribers.paginate(page, 3, False)
next_url=url_for('index', page=friends.next_num) if friends.has_next else None
prev_url=url_for('index', page=friends.prev_num) if friends.has_prev else None
return render_template("index.html", title="My friends", friends=friends.items, next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

This gives a weird result. To start with it returns only 2 results when 3 are asked and friends.has_next is false when it should be true (there are more items in the databse). In [Strange paginate behaviour when paginating a subquery in flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58282132/strange-paginate-behaviour-when-paginating-a-subquery-in-flas) there are more details and also a test I run. I am suspecting the error comes from the subquery. Am I missing something obvious??!!!

In the following example I work with some "fake" data in a flask shell:

```py
>>> sub = db.session.query(Magazine).join(Magazine.subscribers).filter(User.id == 2).subquery()
>>> subscribers = db.session.query(User).select_from(sub).join(Magazine.subscribers)
>>> friends=subscribers.paginate(1, 3, False)
>>> subscribers.all()
[<User 2>, <User 3>, <User 4>, <User 5>, <User 6>]
>>> friends.items
[<User 2>, <User 3>]
>>> friends.has_next
False
>>> friends.has_prev
False
```

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sqlalchemy_paginator`. Check out this [link](https://github.com/ahmadjavedse/sqlalchemy-paginator) for detailed example.

```
from sqlalchemy_paginator import Paginator
query = session.query(MyModel)
paginator = Paginator(query, 5)
for page in paginator:
    print "page number of current page in iterator", page.number
    print "this is a list that contains the records of current page", page.object_list
```